# PowerShell: NEW-ADGroup / creating multiple groups in Active Directory / -Path parameter issue

Tags: powershell, group

in short, this is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzHXu.png)
and this is the script:

```
#
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 
#
$ADGroups = Import-Csv C:\temp\NewGroups.csv -Delimiter ";"

#Create group in "Users"
$OU = "CN=Users"
$Path2 = "CN=Users,DC=master,DC=int"

# Loop through each row containing group details in the CSV file
foreach ($Group in $ADGroups) {

    #Read group data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $groupName = $Group.groupname
    $SAM = $Group.SAMName
    $gCategory = $Group.grouptype
    $gScope = $Group.groupscope
    $dispName = $Group.teamname
    $Path = $Group.path
    $desc = $Group.description
    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADGroup -F { SamAccountName -eq $groupName }) {
        
        # Group existance warning
        Write-Warning "A $groupName group  already exists in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
    Write-Host "This is SAM: $SAM"
    Write-Host "This is Path: $Path"
        
        New-ADGroup `
            -Path $Path `
            -Name "$groupName" `
            -GroupScope $gScope `
            -SamAccountName $SAM `
            -GroupCategory $gCategory `
            -DisplayName $dispName `
            -Description  $desc
                                    
        # If group is created, show message.
        Write-Host "The $groupName group is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    }
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

[The script png version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQDEw.png)
and here is the .csv file:
[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ToSZ.png)

The problem is with the "Path" parameter. If I only skip it, the group is added and apparently the CN=Users will be default, which exactly as described on MS web: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-adgroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps . But I have tried in many ways to use the "Path" variable even more than one to divide CN=Users and DC=... but it always tends to add whatever is in "Name" parameter to to Path as CN. It combines "Name" with "Path" having 2x CN like in the error screen: "CN=Designers,CN=Users,DC=masters,DC=int". I have tried passing variable to Path parameter using double quotes or no quotes - same result.
I have also typed the path manually omitting passing value to PAth using variable - the same.
I don't understand why? Is it reading the .csv file incorrectly?
If I use the below simple script:
[Working simpler script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCkoh.png)
No problems at all...
I have found article where user has passed the value to Path parameter in actually the same way:
[Powershell with Active Directory creating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523625/powershell-with-active-directory-creating-groups)
and there was no problem...

Comment: Can you post the csv in text?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your path is correct? `CN=Designers,CN=Users,DC=masters,DC=int` would likely be `CN=Users,CN=Designers,DC=masters,DC=int`. Try copying the DistinguishedName from the OU in the properties page of UAC to be certain you get it right

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the path. `The server is unwilling to process the request` usually means you are sending bad types of data for one of your fields. Verify that **each** of your variables actually gets filled out correctly. You don't need to quote `"groupName"`

Comment: Hi, thanx for comment and interest in my case.
@GetShifting - csv below
Groupname;SAMName;TeamName;Grouptype;Groupscope;Path;Description
Designers;Design;DesignTeam;security;Global;CN=Users,DC=masters,DC=int;This is Design Team

Comment: @Theo - The problem is that it is not correct, it should be CN=Users,DC=master,DC=int but the script add the CN=Designers from the first column in csv which is Name parameter, dont know why. If I will add "AAA" to Name it will show Path: CN=AAA,CN=Users.... that is the actual problem. I will work on it more I was travelling whole day yesterday had no possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you replied in the comments, I believe the error stems from the way you use the `New-ADGroup` cmdlet using all those backticks. (especially, the first backtick).

Try using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters.

That way you don't need those horrible backticks while the code remains clear and easy to maintain.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ADGroups = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewGroups.csv' -Delimiter ";"

# Loop through each row containing group details in the CSV file
foreach ($Group in $ADGroups) {
    $groupName = $Group.Groupname  # for convenience

    if (Get-ADGroup -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$groupName'") {
        # Group existance warning
        Write-Warning "A $groupName group already exists in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
        # build a Hashtable for splatting the parameters 
        # (no need to put all in separate variables first)
        $groupParams = @{
            Path           = $Group.Path
            Name           = $groupName
            DisplayName    = $Group.TeamName
            SamAccountName = $Group.SAMName
            Description    = $Group.Description
            GroupScope     = $Group.Groupscope
            GroupCategory  = $Group.Grouptype
            ErrorAction    = 'Stop'
        }
        # create the new group
        try {
            New-ADGroup @groupParams
            Write-Host "The $groupName group is created." -ForegroundColor Cyan
        }
        catch {
            # write the error to console and proceed with the next group
            Write-Warning "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sadly it has the same error message but, yes, your script looks a lot clearer, thanks for showing that. What did next was: I have removed line 15 "Path = Group.Path" and it worked..., looks like the issue is the same. Thank you for the efford!

Comment: @woytazeit The newly created group would have `CN=Designers` at the start of **its** `.DistinguishedName`. Is that what you are looking at?

Comment: I have looked into the properties of the created group and "distinguishedName" was actually: CN=Designers,CN=Users,DC=masters,DC=int

Comment: @woytazeit Yes, so it should be.. The group has a name (`CN=Designers`) and is situated in OU `CN=Users,DC=masters,DC=int`

Comment: @woytazeit In fact, the default Users OU is `OU=Users,DC=masters,DC=int`. Did you check that before typing `CN=Users` in the csv?

Comment: yes, I did check that, then it only changes CN to OU but erros stays the same... :(

Comment: Then don't use that faulty path in the CSV, but instead get it from `$path = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit Users).DistinguishedName`. Also make sure you have permissions to create new groups (New-ADGroup also has a `Credential` parameter).